# How can I put a (working) bottom margin on a hovered <a>?

Tags: html, css, margin

I was wondering - when making my website - how i can put a bottom margin that lifts an a-tag up.

CSS:

```
.navbar a {
    background-color: #494949;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #494949;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 1px #494949 solid;
    background-color: #67E727;
}
```

And here's also my html:

```
<div class="navbar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Info</a>
            <a href="#">Doneren</a>
            <a href="#">Gallerij</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

I really hope you can help me out :)

greetings form the Netherlands!

Comment: So you want the link text to move up when hovered on? Or ?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? And what are you doing here? Go watch the game

Comment: set display:inline-block to <a> , so it can behave more like a box

Comment: you need to describe the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to repeat all properties in hover state, only those you want to change. `a` tag is a `inline` element, see how [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) works. To push it top on hover you can't use margin, you can use something like this:

```
.navbar a:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tsHunter/wJfby/) what you're looking for? It moves the whole nav bar down a bit so the highlighting doesn't get cut off, and it moves the text up on hover. Here is the changed parts:

```
.navbar{
        margin-top:20px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```